# Python for-loop runs twice, even with breaks

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on a text-based RPG on my free time for fun, and I've begun implementing barter, thievery, and shopping systems for NPC interactions. Bartering works, as does thievery, but purchasing items for in-game money does not. All of the mechanics work, but for some reason the for-loop runs twice! I even tried implementing an integer to constrain it to one purchase, but it doesn't help either. I've provided the code for the `selltoplayer()` function.

Keep in mind that everything is working, except for the loop continuing after the breaks.

```
def selltoplayer(self, player):
    inv = self.readableinv()  #Give us a viewable inventory
    print("What would you like? I have the following items in stock:\n{0}".format(inv))  #display said inv
    purchaseitem = input("Type the name of the item that you wish to purchase:\n")  #Get the requested item
    timespurchased = 0
    for item in self.inventory:  #search each item in the inventory
        if timespurchased < 1:
            if item.name == purchaseitem:  #once the correct item is found...
                ImportantCalculations.determinevalue(player, item)  #get the item's value
                if player.money >= item.buyvalue:  #and make sure that the player can afford it.
                    confirm = input("So, you would like to purchase {0} for {1} Karics?\n".format(item.name,
                                                                                              item.buyvalue))
                    #Just a simple confirmation
                    if confirm.lower() == 'y' or confirm.lower() == 'yes':  #If the player would like the item
                        print("Thanks for your purchase!")  #the merchant is kind
                        player.inventory.append(item)  #put the item in the player's inventory
                        self.inventory.remove(item)  #take the item out of the merchant's inventory
                        player.money -= item.buyvalue  #withdraw the proper amount of money from the player's stores
                        pinv = player.readableinv()  #Readable inventory for player
                        print(pinv)  #Debug line to make sure that the item was properly transferred
                        print(player.money)  #Debug line to make sure that the money was properly transferred
                        timespurchased += 1
                        break  #stop
                    elif confirm.lower() == 'n' or confirm.lower() == 'no':  #If the player made a mistake
                        print("Oh, okay.")  #Try to guilt the player out of leaving
                        exitsell = input("Would you like to browse again (A) or exit (B)?\n")  #ask if they want to
                        #purchase something different or leave
                        if exitsell.lower() == 'a':  #resell items
                            self.rselltoplayer(player)
                        elif exitsell.lower() == 'b':  #exit
                            print("Thanks for stopping by!")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Sorry, I don't speak gibberish. I'll see you around!")
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Sorry, I don't speak gibberish. I'll see you around!")
                        break
                else:
                    print("I'm sorry, but you cannot afford this...")
                    self.rselltoplayer(player)
        else:
            break
```

Here is what happens when I run the file:

```
What would you like? I have the following items in stock:

['Stick', 'Rock', 'Scarf', 'Explosives', 'Diamond Ring']  #Prints inventory fine

Type the name of the item that you wish to purchase:

Stick

So, you would like to purchase Stick for 104 Karics?    #Interprets player choice properly (including the value)

yes

Thanks for your purchase!  #Interprets confirmation fine

['Stick']  #Prints player inventory fine

396  #Prints player money fine

#Then... It loops again.

What would you like? I have the following items in stock:

['Rock', 'Scarf', 'Explosives', 'Diamond Ring']

Type the name of the item that you wish to purchase:

Scarf

#And doesn't even complete. What's going on?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Feel free to ask if there isn't enough information.

Comment: where is ImportantCalculations gotten from, the program dosen't run when i do a simple copy and paste

Comment: What does `self.rselltoplayer(player)` do?

Comment: Also, where is this called from?

Comment: @danidee I'll update with the console output (because it references many files and objects)

Comment: @Dannnno `self.rselltoplayer(player)` is just a "reset" function. It calls `selltoplayer(player)`

Comment: Check all calls to `selltoplayer(player)` in your code. It is very likely that you call it again somewhere.

Comment: @MikeMüller I checked and the only call to `selltoplayer(player)` is the one that is running. Even replacing the call with `rselltoplayer(player)` I get the same issue.

Comment: i don't agree that it's looping twice the fuction is definitely getting called again because they are statements getting printed to the console before calling `for item in self.inventory`

Comment: @danidee there is no other call anywhere. It is only called once, which runs. _The other part of the problem is that the second time around it doesn't even finish._ **EDIT: It does finish, but it still has only one call.**

Comment: The function is getting called twice..  Even though you call it only once,  there is a chance that it may get executed when you are importing the python file that is calling the function.. ? Can you check that ?  you may also have a testing code that calls these method directly in the file without the check of "if __name__ == '__main__':"

Comment: @vijayalakshmid Haha. Before reading your comment I even thought of that and went through, debugging. It turns out I had a little bit of recursive importing. The problem was that the test run was being called within the recursive file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the original post:

> The problem was recursive importing. If you had the same problem, check your imports.